# Syntax error, unrecognized expression a[href^=http://localhost:8885]

Tags: jquery, wordpress

The console gives me syntax error while get site url and apply background  color to all anchor tag that start with siteURL.

```
var siteURL = "http://" + top.location.host.toString();
$('a[href^=' + siteURL + ']').css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try $('a[href^="' + siteURL + '"]').css("background-color", "yellow");

Comment: Thanks #Pranav C Balan it work fine

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `$('a[href^=' + siteURL + ']')` with  `$('a[href^="' + siteURL + '"]')`.

Comment: You have correctly identified the problem, the missing double quotes, but you've also removed the `^` character. `^` is used to select anchor tags whose href attribute begins with the URL instead of matching the URL completely.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing double quotes around the URL.

Change:

```
$('a[href^=' + siteURL + ']').css("background-color", "yellow");
```

To:

```
$('a[href^="' + siteURL + '"]').css("background-color", "yellow");
```